# Is there a way to hide the "Add a list" bar?

Tags: trello

Trello has a new feature where, to the right of all the lists, there's an "Add a list..." button-thing for quick adding of a list.

The trouble is, this creates a horizontal scroll bar on the board, which looks ugly and seems unnecessary.

Is there a way to disable or hide the "Add a list..." button?

Comment: Agree on this suggestion. As a relevant other example, the "Archive card" area appears on the bottom only when it is applicable (when moving a card). The "Add a list" area always appears and gets horizontal space even if we're perfectly happy with the current set of lists on the board. I don't think that there is a solution yet, but perhaps it could be made a board configuration setting.

Comment: It's broken by design. How such a space eating thing is in a production ready product? Does Trello hire any UI/UEx designer? Shame

Answer (score 4):

One solution that worked so far for me in Google Chrome was to use the [**AdBlock** extension](https://getadblock.com) on the list `DIV`:

- Right-click on the list's `DIV`.
- Select "AdBlock → Remove this".
- Confirm the dialogs.

This removes the item permanently. Since you can still double-click on a blank area to add a list, I miss no option and have additional space.

Comment: You can also do this if you're using uBlock Origin.

Click on the eyedropper next to "on this page" in the uBlock menu when you're on a Trello list.

Click the eyedropper on "Add a list".

In the popup, block ###board .js-add-list (there will be other things listed, this is all you need to hide "Add a list".

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help me as I am using the new desktop app so blocking elements is not possible. Funnily enough the Add a List... never bothered me in the browser as my standard browser width is wide enough to accommodate it without scrolling. Now I'm using the app I would like to be able to size my board windows to fit my lists without the scroll bar appearing.